# Алгоритм определения угла поворота изображения

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Имеется файл с изображением книжной страницы, которая повернута на некоторый угол относительно оси координат. Попадался ли кому-нибудь алгоритм обработки изображения, с помощью которого можно бы было определить этот угол для последующего поворота изображения?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать `Principal Component Analysis` (метод главных компонент) для извлечения угла поворота объекта на изображении.

Для начало придётся найти контуры объекта, приведя перед этим изображение к бинарному виду. В OpenCV это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
cv::Mat src_mat = cv::imread("source_image.jpg");

cv::Mat gry_mat;
cv::cvtColor(src_mat, gry_mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::threshold(gry_mat, gry_mat, 150, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
```

Значение `150` в данном примере подбирается под изображение. Либо вместо метода `threshold()` можно попробовать использовать адаптивный - `adaptiveThreshold()`.

Затем находим контуры:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(gry_mat, contours, hierarchy
    , cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

В цикле проходим по каждому обнаруженному контуру:

```
for(int i = 0, n = contours.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    const std::vector<cv::Point> &contour = contours.at(i);

    // Отсеиваем слишком маленькие, либо слишком большие.
    double area = cv::contourArea(contour);
    if(area < 1e2 || 1e5 < area) continue;

    // Строим буфер для PCA.
    cv::Mat pts_mat(contour.size(), 2, CV_64FC1);
    for(int j = 0; j < pts_mat.rows; ++j) {
        pts_mat.at<double>(j,0) = pts[j].x;
        pts_mat.at<double>(j,1) = pts[j].y;
    }

    cv::PCA pca(pts_mat, cv::Mat(), cv::PCA::DATA_AS_ROW);

    // В отдельный вектор выносим собственные вектора,
    // полученные при помощи PCA.
    std::vector<cv::Point2d> eigen_vecs(2);
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
        eigen_vecs[j]
            = cv::Point2d(pca.eigenvectors.at<double>(j,0)
                , pca.eigenvectors.at<double>(j,1));
    }

    // Искомый угол.
    double angle = std::atan2(eigen_vecs[0].y, eigen_vecs[0].x);
}
```

Подробнее по теме с примером кода можно почитать [по ссылке](https://robospace.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/object-orientation-principal-component-analysis-opencv/).

**Дополнение**

В общем случае поворот изображения можно осуществить при помощи функций `getRotationMatrix2D()` и `warpAffine()`. Сначала получаем матрицу поворота:

```
cv::Mat rot_mat = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1);
```

... где, `center` - точка центра контура или самого изображения, `angle` - угол, на который следует осуществить поворот. Последний аргумент позволяет произвести масштабирование. Значение, равное "1", означает, что объект должен сохранить свой размер неизменным.

Далее производим т.н. аффинное преобразование:

```
cv::Mat dst_mat;
cv::warpAffine(src_mat, dst_mat, rot_mat, src_mat.size(), cv::INTER_CUBIC);
```

Первым и вторым аргументами являются входное и выходное изображение соответственно. Третий - матрица преобразования. Четвёртый - размер выходного изображения. Этот параметр определяется отдельно по той причине, что повёрнутое изображение часто становится больше исходного из-за выступающих углов. Последним в примере аргументом функции является флаг, влияющий на качество выходного изображения. У `warpAffine` также имеется ещё несколько аргументов, которым при вызове функции присваиваются значения по умолчанию. Ознакомиться с ними можно на странице [справки](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpaffine).

Comment: а что делать дальше? Алгоритм нашёл и пометил кучу точек на изображении. Как теперь зная их повернуть изображение?