# is_block_type_valid(header-> _block_use)

Tags: c++, opencv

Доброго времени суток.

Дали задание: найти угол наклона объекта (в моём случае лопасти вертолёта) и вывести всё видеопотоком.
Используй VS2015 и OpenCV 2.4.13
Нашёл пример на этом сайте : [Алгоритм определения угла поворота изображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446250/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/446262#446262?newreg=712e01632bca4a57a4fcf4d1b8825c6a). Очень помог но возникли проблемы и некоторые я решил, некоторые нет:

В начале она жаловался на строку

```
pts_mat.at<double>(j,0) = pts[j].x;
```

решил проблему изменив переменную pts[j].x на contoue[j].x и y соответственно. Позже разгадывал необходимые библиотеки.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
double angle;
int main();
{
    Mat src_mat = imread("E:/work/project/opencv/Find_object/Find_object/blade2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    imshow("blade", src_mat);
    if (src_mat.empty() == NULL)
    {
        cout << "File not find!";
    }
    Mat gry_mat;
    cvtColor(src_mat, gry_mat, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(gry_mat, gry_mat, 150, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(gry_mat, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST,  CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    int sz = static_cast<int>(contours.size());
    for (int i = 0, n = contours.size(); i < n; ++i)
    {
         const vector<Point> &contour = contours.at(i);

         // Отсеиваем слишком маленькие, либо слишком большие.
        double area = contourArea(contour);
        if (area < 1e2 || 1e5 < area) continue;

        // Строим буфер для PCA.
        int sz = static_cast<int>(contour.size());
        Mat pts_mat = Mat (sz, 2, CV_64FC1);
        for (int j = 0; j < pts_mat.rows; ++j) 
        {
            pts_mat.at<double>(j, 0) = contour[j].x;
            pts_mat.at<double>(j, 1) = contour[j].y;
        }

        PCA pca(pts_mat, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW);

        // В отдельный вектор выносим собственные вектора,
        // полученные при помощи PCA.
        vector<Point2d> eigen_vecs(2);
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            eigen_vecs[j] = Point2d(pca.eigenvectors.at<double>(j, 0), pca.eigenvectors.at<double>(j, 1));
        }

        // Искомый угол.
        angle = atan2(eigen_vecs[0].y, eigen_vecs[0].x);
        cout << "Angin[" << i << "] =" << angle << "\n";
     }
     return angle;
}
```

всё срабатывает, высчитывает, но выводиться ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выходит после работы всей программы.
Помогите пожалуйста.

необходимые dll :
core, highgui, imgproc;

Comment: Скорее всего, данеая ошибка - поврежление кучи. Проверяйте работу с памятью (границы массивов, двойное удаление, etc).

Comment: Попробуйте создать [mcve]. Если в процессе его создания ошибка не будет обнаружена самостоятельно - другим участникам Сообщества будет легче Вам помочь.

Comment: Спасибо большое! закомментировал почти весь код, и начал по смылу востанавливать. объявления вынес из цикла и всё заработало.